# [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Tags: objective-c, crash, nsarray, nsdictionary

I want to create an *NSArray* populating of *NSDictionary* and print in console the first value of every array's element.

I receive the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException',
>   reason:' -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
>   *** First throw call stack:   (0x30d77e83 0x3b0d46c7 0x30cadd95 0xb93b3 0xb8e03 0x3175ccdd 0x30d42e7f 0x30d42a9b 0x30d40e23 0x30cab471
>   0x30cab253 0x359e52eb 0x33560845 0xb8abd 0x3b5cdab7)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

```
-(void) listOp {
    NSDictionary *dictionary;
    NSMutableArray *array;
    NSNumber    *refNum;

    int numOp = [_refNum intValue];

    self.array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: self.dictionary, nil];
    for ( int i = 0; i < numOp; i++){
        [self.array insertObject:self.dictionary atIndex:i];

        NSDictionary* vardebug = nil;
        vardebug = [self.array objectAtIndex:numOp];
        NSString *valuekey = [self.dictionary valueForKey: @"key"];

        NSLog(@"Valuekey is: %@", valuekey);
    }
}
```

Don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Let's say numOp=5.
In the first iteration of your for loop, self.array doesn't have an object at index 5 (when you want to get vardebug), it only has 2 objects.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little bit messy. You declare:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary;
NSMutableArray *array;
```

And after that you call

```
self.dictionary...
self.array...
```

You use self if you have property, for example;

@`property(nonatomic, strong)  NSDictionary *dictionary;`

so basically if you want to access your:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary;
NSMutableArray *array;
```

you should call, for example:

```
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: dictionary, nil];
```

Without self. But maybe you have both ivar shown in this example and property and you do it by purpose. I just want to say that if you do it by purpose you should use different names just to make your code more clear.

The error you have happened in line:

```
vardebug = [self.array objectAtIndex:numOp];
```

In your first loop iteration you have already one item in the array (added during allocation) and you insert another one so you array contains 2 object but you numOp is equal 2 which refer to 3rd object in the array (array are zero base) so the call is  beyond bounds. I guess you want to change it to:

```
vardebug = [self.array objectAtIndex:i];
```

Hope this help

Comment: Yes, i've added this declaration in the function, but those are declared in the .h like property, so i call from the function.  Thanks for help, it's a slip.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `vardebug = [self.array objectAtIndex:numOp];` by `vardebug = [self.array objectAtIndex:i];` should avoid the crash.

Comment: When you have some item in NSMutableArray at index 0 and after that you insert another item at index 0 the app won't crash it will insert the second item at index 0 and it moves first item at index 1.